# How can I get W3 Total Cache to recognise Amazon ElastiCache?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

What I did (on my EC2 instance):

a) Followed Amazon's instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.html) to install their special PHP Memcached Extension for ElastiCache.

b) Confirmed it was installed and restarted apache

```
$ php -i | grep memcached
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcached.ini,
memcached
memcached support => enabled
libmemcached version => 1.0.4
memcached.compression_factor => 1.3 => 1.3
memcached.compression_threshold => 2000 => 2000
memcached.compression_type => fastlz => fastlz
memcached.serializer => php => php
memcached.sess_binary => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_consistent_hash => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_lock_wait => 150000 => 150000
memcached.sess_locking => 1 => 1
memcached.sess_number_of_replicas => 0 => 0
memcached.sess_prefix => memc.sess.key. => memc.sess.key.
memcached.sess_randomize_replica_read => 0 => 0
Registered save handlers => files user memcached
```

c) Confirmed I could send and retrieve objects using the script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313979/751089) (I could).

d) Updated `wp-content/w3tc-config/master.php` with the full address and port of my ElastiCache instance wherever it was pointing to `127.0.0.1:11211`.

e) Tried and failed to figure out why I still can't select Memcached from the w3tc dropdown.